# PL/SQL Displaying multiple records using function

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table `Iss_rec` with the following fields:

```
Iss_No
Iss_date
Mem_No
Book_No
Fine
```

I need to print the record(s) having the maximum fine using a user defined function.
If it was only one record I can print it easily but for multiple rows I have no idea what to do. Searching online showed me results where people use cursors but I would like to do it using functions alone.

Lets say the data is:

```
165 12-Apr-14 15677 978453 50  
166 18-Jun-14 15678 978454 50  
167 29-Sep-14 15679 978455 25  
168 1-Oct-14  15677 978456 0  
169 6-Nov-14  15676 978457 0
```

Now I want to print the first two records since they have the maximum fine using a user defined function.

Something like this?

```
create or replace function maxf
return number is
total number;
begin
select r.mem_no into total from iss_rec r group by r.mem_no having 
r.fine=max(r.fine); return total;
end;
/
```

Comment: add some sample data and expected outcome, make it easier to follow

Comment: Print records? In PL/SQL you can loop through data and output it via `dbms_output.put_line`. If you want the function to return rows instead, you can create a pipelined function and query it with `select * from table(myfunction)`.

Comment: Do you have anything to share if you tried something or expectation is to get working code from SO ?

Comment: @dbajtr added some sample data

Comment: @XING added something I came up with...But it doesnt work...atleast for multiple rows...

Comment: Use @Tenzin query inside a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to print the record(s) having the maximum fine using a user
>   defined function.

You can use a `sys_refcursor` to print values:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE FINE
(
  COL1  NUMBER,
  COL2  DATE,
  COL3  NUMBER,
  COL4  NUMBER,
  COL5  NUMBER
)
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maxf
   RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
   total  sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
   Open total for  
   SELECT * 
        FROM fine  
    WHERE col5 IN (SELECT MAX(col5) FROM fine);
   RETURN total;
END;
/
```

Execution

```
DECLARE
   var   fine%ROWTYPE;
   x     SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   x := maxf ();

   LOOP
      FETCH x INTO var;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         var.col1 ||' '|| var.col2 ||' '||  var.col3 || ' '|| var.col4 ||' '||  var.col5);

      EXIT WHEN x%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Output:

```
SQL> /
165 12-APR-14 15677 978453 50
166 18-JUN-14 15678 978454 50


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

OR

```
SQL> Select maxf from dual;

MAXF
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

      COL1 COL2            COL3       COL4       COL5
---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       165 12-APR-14      15677     978453         50
       166 18-JUN-14      15678     978454         50
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to select only the rows that have the max fine you could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Iss_rec 
WHERE Fine IN (SELECT MAX(Fine) FROM Iss_rec);
```

Comment: I`d like to use a user defined function to do the same.